# Как исключить мета поле в запросе get_posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, запрос

В цикле **wordpress** есть запрос `get_posts` произвольного типа, в выводе которого нужно исключить мета поле `cp_category` со значением "Шины" и полностью мета поле `cp_new`.
С первой частью справился на ура вот так:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_query' => array( 
                      array('key' => 'cp_category', 
                            'value' => 'Шины', 
                            'compare' => '!='
                            )
                     ), 
);

$categories = get_posts( $args );
```

А вот с исключением целого мета поля у меня возникли проблемы - далаю так, но в таком случае исключается не само поле, а значения в нем.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_query' => array( 
                     'relation' => 'AND',
      array('key' => 'cp_category', 
            'value' => 'Шины', 
            'compare' => '!='
                  ),
                        array('key' => 'cp_new', 
            'compare' => '!='
                  )
         ), 
);

$categories = get_posts( $args );
```

Как можно решить?

Answer (score 0):

Решение такое - нужно указать `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'`

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_query' => array( 
                     'relation' => 'AND',
      array('key' => 'cp_category', 
            'value' => 'Шины', 
            'compare' => '!='
                  ),
                        array('key' => 'cp_new', 
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                  )
         ), 
);

$categories = get_posts( $args );
```